# Transparent area with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am adding a polygon to an image like this:

```
image = Map.objects.all()[0].image
back = Image.open(image.path)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(back)
poly = Image.new('RGBA', (image.width,image.height))
pdraw = ImageDraw.Draw(poly)
pdraw.polygon(list(group(self.coords.split(","), 2)),fill=(255,255,255,127),outline=(255,255,255,255))
back.paste(poly,mask=poly)
back.show()
```

So this opens up the image with the polygon in the correct area etc.

**But I want the polygon it self to be semi transparent, like an opacity of 0.8, so that the polygon is just a color overlay and you can still see though it.**

**Transparency in my mind has an opacity less than 1? Or is this not what it means**

Am I missing something?

This is what the image looks like now

[image]

Comment: Could you give a more detailed description of your problem? I definitely just succeeded drawing a transparent polygon over a jpg image using parts of your code.

Comment: Transparent in my mind is something that you can see through, opacity been less than 1

Comment: Sure, but, first of all, it's difficult to tell from your huge picture what's wrong with it. I suspect, the problem is that gray deformed rectangle on the left? Second, as I said it works. And I certainly know what “transparent” means, and when I say that it worked, that's exatly what I mean. Probably you've got a problem somewhere else in your code.

Comment: That grey rectangle is the polygon I am drawing on the image. That is all the code I am using to do this. Ok, so just to be sure, what I am doing is correct to make the image opacity less than 1 right?

Comment: It is correct and works for me with jpg. But your question doesn't contain enough details. For example, what format does your original image have. An answer by James Holderness suggests that it's probably grayscale GIF. You should have mentioned that.

Comment: Ok, you are correct. Its does work with a jpg and yes this is a GIF. Damn, sorry, at least I learnt something.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the mode of your source image does not support transparency. You can likely correct the problem by adding the following lines after opening the image.

```
if back.mode not in ['RGB','RGBA']:
  back = back.convert('RGB')
```

Quoting the [PIL documentation for Image.paste](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#image.paste):

> If the modes don't match, the pasted image is converted to the mode of this image

**Update**: I've changed the condition so that it doesn't perform the `convert` if the mode is already RGBA, which obviously shouldn't need to be converted. There may be other modes that don't require conversion, but those are the ones that definitely seem to work as is.

Comment: That's not true. You can happily paste RGBA transparent images into RGB ones and this works as expected.

Comment: @kirelagin But you can't paste transparent over monochrome, and I suspect not grayscale either. I've been able to reproduce this problem with monochrome images and those lines fixes it. It's not that the destination has to have transparency - but not all modes support pasting transparency it seems.

Comment: Hmmm… ok, sounds reasonable.

Comment: Thanks, my problem was that the image was a gray GIF. Once the image was replaced with a png it worked like it should.